# Bash, Perl or Sed, Insert on New Line after found phrase

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk

Ok I guess I need something that will do the following:

search for this line of code in `/var/lib/asterisk/bin/retrieve_conf`:

```
$engineinfo = engine_getinfo();
```

insert these two lines immediately following:

```
$engineinfo['engine']="asterisk";
$engineinfo['version']="1.6.2.11";
```

Thanks in advance,
Joe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
sed -ne '/$engineinfo = engine_getinfo();/a\'$'\n''$engineinfo['engine']="asterisk";\'$'\n''$engineinfo['version']="1.6.2.11";'$'\n'';p' /var/lib/asterisk/bin/retrieve_conf
```

Add `-i` for modification in place once you confirm that it works.

What does it do and how does it work?

First we tell sed to match a line containing your string. On that matched line we then will perform an `a` command, which is "append text".

The syntax of a sed `a` command is

```
a\
line of text\
another line
;
```

Note that the literal newlines are part of this syntax. To make it all one line (and preserve copy-paste ability) in place of literal newlines I used `$'\n'` which will tell bash or zsh to insert a real newline in place. The quoting necessary to make this work is a little complex: You have to exit single-quotes so that you can have the `$'\n'` be interpreted by bash, then you have to re-enter a single-quoted string to prevent bash from interpreting the rest of your input.

EDIT: Updated to append both lines in one append command.

Comment: In my experience, you can append multiple lines in one "a" command: all lines except the last require a backslash continuation.

Comment: you'll need to escape the backslash characters, or else you're escaping the single quote.

Comment: @glenn: I'm not sure your correct. It works as is and fails with additional escaping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Perl and [`Tie::File`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html) (included in the Perl distribution):

```
use Tie::File;
tie my @array, 'Tie::File', "/var/lib/asterisk/bin/retrieve_conf" or die $!; 
for (0..$#array) {
    if ($array[$_] =~ /\$engineinfo = engine_getinfo\(\);/) {
        splice @array, $_+1, 0, q{$engineinfo['engine']="asterisk"; $engineinfo['version']="1.6.2.11";};
        last;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of symmetry here's an answer using awk.

```
awk '{ if(/\$engineinfo = engine_getinfo\(\);/) print $0"\n$engineinfo['\''engine'\'']=\"asterisk\";\n$engineinfo['\''version'\'']=\"1.6.2.11\"" ; else  print $0 }' in.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use `ed`:

```
# cf. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed
cat <<-'EOF' | ed -s /var/lib/asterisk/bin/retrieve_conf
H
/\$engineinfo = engine_getinfo();/a
$engineinfo['engine']="asterisk";
$engineinfo['version']="1.6.2.11";
.
wq
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

A Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pE 's|(\$engineinfo) = engine_getinfo\(\);.*\K|\n${1}['\''engine'\'']="asterisk";\n${1}['\''version'\'']="1.6.2.11";|' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i  's/$engineinfo = engine_getinfo();/$engineinfo = engine_getinfo();<CTRL V><CNTRL M>$engineinfo['engine']="asterisk"; $engineinfo['version']="1.6.2.11";/' /var/lib/asterisk/bin/retrieve_conf
```

Comment: Like I said, I know you can use sed -i.  I just thought the sed command was already too long and was trying to make it more brief.

Comment: This isn't about having or not having `-i`, which would not work with your version anyway since it's reading from a pipe. To make it more brief you can omit the `cat` invocation, which is useless. E.g. `sed 's/../.../' /var/lib/asterisk/bin/retrieve_conf`

Comment: yes, obviously getting rid of the cat would be a precondition to using -i on sed, but it would make the sed command even longer.  This is why I said "just trying to make it readable."  BTW, The command you entered would change the file then throw the change away - not terribly useful.

Comment: The command *you* entered would do the same thing, so it's equivalent.